# Float Precision Format to suppress trailing zeros

Tags: c#, .net, double

I am using the format string `F2` to convert a double value. I am getting the formatted value as `9999.00`, if the double value is `9999`

Which format string should I use to avoid trailing zeroes in `9999.00`?

To be more clear, the output I need is when given the arguments on the left I receive the outputs on the right

```
1.211 -> 1.21
1.245 -> 1.25
1.1   -> 1.1
1     -> 1
```

Is there any standard string format to do that?

Comment: Those are *trailing zeros*. Leading zeros would be 0009999.

Comment: The documentation is here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: What format would you *like* to see? Not only for values without decimal places, but also values *with* them?

Comment: Edited question to include additional context from comment provided on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15803378/414076).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize format strings including `#` to optionally include up to a given number of decimal places, but not more than required. For example, you could use the format string `"0.##"`.

```
double d = 1.245;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.##"));
```

Which would yield 1.25. The same format string would yield `1.1` as the output when given an argument with that value.

Answer (score 4):

The string you want is F0.

The documentation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
double d = 9999;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("F0"));
```

Outpur will be;

```
9999
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/IUcaIf).

Check for more information from [`Standard Numeric Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: The value and output i need is given - 1.211 -> 1.21, 1.245->1.25, 1.1-> 1.1, 1->1. Is there any standard string format to do that?

Comment: @Maanu _Hmm_, I don't see any regular pattern for all of these, I suggest you should use seperate formats for them..